# Condition for category of algebras over a monoid in a monoidal category to be regular

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

The category of algebras over a monad over a category $\mathcal{A}$ is regular, if $\mathcal{A}$ is. A monad is a monoid in the monoidal category $(\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{A},\circ,\dots)$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is regular, then so is $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{A}$.

This suggests that there is a reasonable condition we can put on a monoidal category $\mathcal{X}$ such that for every monoid $M$ in $\mathcal{X}$ the category of modules over $M$ is regular.

> Is this a reasonable hypothesis and is anything known about this idea?